# Removing CSS transitionend event listener not working

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I have a problem trying to remove a css transistionend event listener.  I am able to add the listener with:

```
e.addEventListener('transitionend',function(event) {
    transitionComplete( event.propertyName );
},false);
```

I am trying to remove it with

```
e.removeEventListener('transitionend',function(event) {
    transitionComplete( event.propertyName );
},false);
```

No matter where I put the removeEventListener the listen does not get removed.  What can I be doing wrong?

I am not using jquery for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use an anonymous function, instead name the function and put the removal in the event handler.

```
var func = function(event) {
   transitionComplete( event.propertyName );
    e.removeEventListener('transitionend',func);
};

e.addEventListener('transitionend',func, false);
```

Comment: Well that worked thanks! Just need to studying as to why, so I know for future ref. ;-)

Comment: In your original code, the function you are trying to remove from the handler is a new anonymous function that just happens to be equivalent to the anonymous function you added, however it isn't actually the same function (i.e. the same reference) so your originally added function stays on the handler. In this code, func points to the same reference. I hope this makes sense, there may be better explanations elsewhere on SO!

Comment: This works but I can't figure it out. On the `removeEventListener` you are calling the `func` in which it is contained. You are calling itself. Are you able to explain this more?

Comment: @AlexMcCabe the second parameter to removeEventListener is not calling func, it is merely passing through a function, it doesn't evaluate the function.

Comment: @Eterm I tried passing an anonymous function or an empty function to it, to see what it would do, and it doesn't work. It doesn't detach the transition `eventListener`. _To be clear, I have your code working, I am just trying to understand what it does._