# VueX wait for modal to close before reopening with new data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to ensure a smooth transition with a vue modal ([the one in the guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html)). My VueX store.js file contains this mutation:

```
swapModalView (state, view) {
  state.modalView = 'none'
  state.modalView = view
}
```

The modal closes when the view is set to "none," and reopens when it's anything else.

```
<VueModal v-if="modalView != 'none'"></VueModal>
```

It's probably pretty simple, but how can I change the view to "none," and then set it to the view being passed **after the transition ends**? I would think I could just do it here, in the mutation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Just basic setting up an event listener for a css transition, which I never did without copying some code somewhere.

```
swapModalView (state, view) {
  let modal = document.getElementById('locustModal')
  var launchNew = function (event) {
    state.modalView = view
    modal.removeEventListener('transitionend', launchNew)
  }
  state.modalView = 'none'
  modal.addEventListener('transitionend', launchNew, false)
}
```

Comment: I suggest you also remove the event listener in the `transitionend` callback using `element.removeEventListener()` if `swapModalView` is able to be called multiple times. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: OK, I'll update the answer. I found an answer that seems to show how this is done, but I'm not quite sure if all of it is necessary or if it could be done simpler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273072/removing-css-transitionend-event-listener-not-working